# Problems with timeout on sync between server and mobile

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails-4, retrofit2, ormlite

I am facing a problem during a data synchronization between the server and the android app, I have already searched but did not find a good solution. Maybe someone has some idea to help me...

Just to explain how my application works, I have an android app that can work offline and then can be synchronized with the rails server. To work offline, at login I sync all tables/records from the server and save everything to the app database. In the app I save both id_server and id_mobile, when the application is working offline only the id_mobile is generated, then a POST request is made to create the record on the server and in return I get some data like id_server, created_at, updated_at and deleted_at and update de record on my app database.

My problem is when I make a POST request to create the data on the server, the server receives the request and processes, when the server is returning the request to the app, timeout happens because of a bad internet, at that time I do not have the record of the server to update the id_server, created_at, updated_at and deleted_at of the record in the app database!

At the next synchronization, this record will continue without the id_server, and will send a POST again, so the record is duplicating...

Any ideas how to prevent this problem?

Answer (score 0):

increase your connection timeout.
if you use volley then you have to do something like this -

```
 stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(15000, 0, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
```

here **15000** is the time out milliseconds.make it **50000** milliseconds like 50 seconds
and your problem will be solved.

and also if you use httpurl connection in raw then just put this line-

```
  httpURLConnection.setConnectTimeout(50000);
```

Comment: but using too much time is bad, is not it?

Comment: nope its not bad.it is a need of us.sometimes we have to work with slow server which response slowly or internet is slow in that case we have to increase connection timeout. if this answer solve your problem please mark it as accepted